# How to make this UINavigationController seeking code more elegant?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

```
-(UINavigationController *) navigationControllerOfParentOrSelf //These 2 functions are short so I just go ahead
{
    UIViewController * current=self;
    while (current) {
        UINavigationController * nav = current.navigationController;
        if (nav) {
            return nav;
        }
        current=current.parentViewController;
    }
    return nil;
}

-(UITabBarController *) tabBarControllerOfParentOrSelf
{
    UIViewController * current=self;
    while (current) {
        UITabBarController * tc = current.tabBarController;
        if (tc) {
            return tc;
        }
        current=current.parentViewController;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Looks like a lot of repeated code there.

Basically I just want to know whether a UIViewController is inside a UINavigationController or not. The thing is navigationController property is often nil when the UIViewController is a childViewController

Comment: Your loop makes no sense. It will execute once if `navigationController` property is not nil. If it's nil it will run for ever.

Comment: fixed. Okay that's not the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest something like this:

```
-(UINavigationController *) navigationControllerOfParentOrSelf
{
    return [self parrentControllerOfParrentOrSelfWithGetter: @selector(navigationController)];
}

-(UITabBarController *) tabBarControllerOfParentOrSelf
{
    return [self parrentControllerOfParrentOrSelfWithGetter: @selector(tabBarController)];

}

- (id) parrentControllerOfParrentOrSelfWithGetter: (SEL) getter
{
    UIViewController * current=self;
    while (current) {
        id res = [current performSelector: getter];
        if (res) {
            return tc;
        }
        current=current.parentViewController;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Nice Answer, better than mine :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like:

```
-(id) getViewController:(BOOL)isNavController
{
     id controller = nil;
     if(isNavController)
     {
        controller  = self.navigationController;
     }
     else
     {
         controller  = self.tabBarController;
     }

     return controller;
}
```

Comment: That's an improvement. The thing is we uses a bool variable. What about if we latter want to add more property. I am thinking something along performSelector(@navigationController)